# kendo chart dynamic series from category, value, seriesName

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-chart

I am using asp.net mvc 5 and KendoUi charts.
I want to create line chart that vertical axis is Poulation, horizantal axis is Year and for each country add series. Country List is not fixed.
how can i do it?

My model is:

```
public class ChartDataViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Poulation { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; } 
}
```

my Controller:

```
public ActionResult ChartPage()
{
    var model = GetData().Select(item => new ChartDataViewModel
    {
        Year = item.Year,
        Population = item.Population,
        Country = item.Country,
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

My Razor View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("mychart")
    .Series(series =>
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Select(item => item.Country).Distinct().ToList())
        {
            series.Line(m => m.Country).Field(item).CategoryField("Year");
        }
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Labels(labels => labels.Padding(0).Rotation(0))
        .Categories(m=> m.Year)
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true))
        .Line(line => line.Visible(true))
        .Name("Poulation")
    )
)
```